# Command does not work during discord bot creation

Tags: python, discord

I typed !mycommand2 [name] [role] because it didn't come out even when I typed command !캐릭터생성 [name] [role], but it's still the same. Why? And description's role(Is it like an annotation? Explain to the developer what command this is without a role?) and...I also wonder about command hidden.
char = I want to mack a instance.....char.py has class char.

```
import discord, asyncio
import char
from discord.ext import commands

intents=discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!',intents=intents,help_command=None)

@client.event
async def on_ready(): 
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game("언성듀엣!"))


@bot.command(name="테스트", description="테스트용 함수", hidden=False) #set hidden to True to hide it in the help
async def mycommand1(ctx, argument1, argument2):
    await ctx.channel.send ("{} | {}, Hello".format(ctx.author, ctx.author.mention))
    await ctx.author.send ("{} | {}, User, Hello".format(ctx.author, ctx.author.mention))
char_num = 1

@bot.command(name="캐릭터생성", description="테스트용 함수", hidden=False) #set hidden to True to hide it in the help
async def mycommand2(ctx, context1, context2):
    global char_num
    globals()['char_{}'.format(char_num)]=char(name=context1,Sffter=context2,username=ctx.author.name)
    char_num+=1
    await ctx.message.channel.send ("done", context1,"!")



client.run('-')
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the function name to the command name

```
async def urcommandname(ctx,arg1,arg2):
```